# Migrations can't run due to evaluation of QuerySet in Serializer?

Tags: django, django-migrations

Trying to solve this chicken-and-egg issue. I've defined a new model which an existing model foreign keys into, and made the new migrations, including a data migration that provisions some defaults for the new model.

In the serializer for the existing model, I wanted to define a default like so:

```
new_thing = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    queryset=NewThing.objects.all(),
    default=NewThing.objects.get(id=DEFAULT_NEW_THING_ID),
)
```

I don't understand django's specific mechanism, but this seems to cause problems while running the migrations (although the makemigrations seems fine). It seems the migration runs a series of app checks on the views and eventually the serializer, where it evaluates the NewThing QuerySet and returns an error that the relation for NewThing does not exist (since the migration hasn't been run yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never run actual queries in class-level definitions; this is generally true in both Django generally as well as DRF. `get` is a query and will hit the database at definition time, although the `queryset` argument will not and is OK.

If you want to set a default that is based on an actual object, you should do it at create time by defining the `create()` method, in which you would check that the value is not supplied.